# Expresiones Regulares Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I have a problem I want to compare values ​​from Column A that exist in Column B, regardless of the order they are in Column B

Ex:

```
Column A 177                           Column B 177 
Column A 2 : 3 : 1 : 18 : 123 : 170    Column B 18 : 123 : 3 : 2 : 3 : 1 : 1
Column A 2 : 3 : 177 : 123             Column B 3 : 123 : 2 : 177
Column A 2 : 3 : 1 : 123 : 177         Column B 1 : 123 : 2 : 3 : 3 : 1
Column A 172                           Column B 1
Column A 2 : 3 : 1 : 18 : 123 : 177    Column B 3 : 1 : 18 : 123 : 3 : 2 : 1
```

We can see that the first record OK
second record, NO, since the value 170 does not exist
third registration, OK, although the order is not the same as column A, but there are values

fourth record, No
Fifth record, No
Sixth Registor No

Thank you very much for the help friends!

I'm using Oragle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve string to table functionality in SQL.

As explained [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=412), the below snippet would be a good start. You can extend the below by changing the delimiter to `:` instead of `,` and then include `DENSE RANK` to compare the column values within the group. Once you break the string into multiple rows then you can easily compare. So instead of a direct check like `C1 = C2` you may include the `DENSE RANK` values to nail this.

I don't have access to any Oracle instance for a fiddle or test and even sqlfiddle.com is broken for ages now. But this pointer should help you in some way. The link I have included contains multiple choices for this functionality.

```
SQL> SELECT str
  2  ,      REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS single_element
  3  ,      LEVEL                                 AS element_no
  4  FROM  (
  5         SELECT ROWNUM AS id
  6         ,      str
  7         FROM   t
  8        )
  9  CONNECT BY INSTR(str, ',', 1, LEVEL-1) > 0
10         AND id = PRIOR id
11         AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL;

STR                            SINGLE_ELEMENT                 ELEMENT_NO
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
X,Y,Z                          X                                       1
X,Y,Z                          Y                                       2
X,Y,Z                          Z                                       3
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG XXX                                     1
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG Y                                       2
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG ZZ                                      3
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG AAAAA                                   4
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG B                                       5
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG CCC                                     6
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG D                                       7
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG E                                       8
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG F                                       9
XXX,Y,ZZ,AAAAA,B,CCC,D,E,F,GGG GGG                                    10
```